# A shorter formulation of singular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

For  definition of singular  homology we normally consider the  chain space $C_{n}(X)= \text{The  free Abelian group generated by all continuous images in  X of the  standard simplex }  \Delta^n$.

Why is   not  it defined simply  by replacement  of  $\Delta^n$ by the closed  unit  disk $\overline{D^n}$. The  boundary   consist  of two positive  and  negative  hemi sphere, each hemi sphere  canonically  homeomorphic  to $\overline{D^{n-1}}$. So in the  boundary operator, we just have  two terms  rather  than $n+1$ terms.  In this  case  the  prism operator, which  is  needed for proof  of  homotopy  invariance  of  continuous maps,  can be  defined easier  than the standard case?

So  why    is  not  a  usual conduct  to define  the homology  in this  manner?Are there  some  technical obstruction? If  not, in teaching algebraic topology, why do we  choose  the  long way  of  standard simplex(with n+1 faces)?

I

Comment: With this definition, the homology groups of a point are all Z.

Comment: @MikeMiller  Why  all homology $\simeq \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Consider the triangle in $\Bbb R^2$ (the sum of three line segments, which are each continuous images of $\overline{D^1}$). Is this the boundary of any 2-chain in your new definition?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger  yes  because  $\overline{D^1}$  is  homeomorphic to $\Delta^2$

Comment: @AliTaghavi You mean $\Delta^1$, not $\Delta^2$. And that doesn't answer my question. It is the boundary of a 2-chain in the usual definition (in terms of $\Delta$s), but I want to know if it could be the boundary of a 2-chain in your new definition (in terms of $\overline D$s).

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger  Sorry $\Delta^1$.   yes let  p  be  a point in the interior  of  the  triangle. Connect it to the 3  vertices . So we  have 3 triangles. The convex hall of  each triangle is the image of  a  $\overline{D^2}$.  So a triangle is the  boundary  of  a chain with 3 terms. Right.

Comment: The situation is similar to the following question in the normal situation: Is  a polygon  with at least 4 edges,  the boundary  of a chain in singular homology? The answer is obviously yes. Now in our case the situaion s the same

Comment: A related paper is `A new higher homotopy groupoid: the fundamental globular omega-groupoid of a filtered space', Homotopy, homology and applications, 10 (2008), No. 1, pp.327-343. However to make this **globular** theory work this paper goes via a well developed cubical theory, which itself is explained in the book "Nonabelian Algebraic Topology" (EMS, 2011). There is no simplicial theory doing  most of the things in that book. Thus the apparent "simplicity" of a possible  globular theory is in my view deceptive, as it seems  not to do what one  wants.

Comment: @AliTaghavi That doesn't actually work. Remember that in your definition, the boundary of a 2-disk is two 1-disks (line segments). What exactly are the two boundary lines of each disk in your proposed 2-chain? Do the boundaries really add up to my 1-chain?

Comment: Perhaps a parity argument will help clear things up: in your definition, the boundary of a 2-chain will be the sum of an _even number_ of 1-disks, even if some terms cancel out (since they always cancel out in pairs). My triangle is three 1-disks, so it can't be the boundary of any 2-chain.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger  "That does not actually..."Please compare the situation with the following: How  a 4-edge polygon is  a "boundary " in the usual sense, while $\Delta^2$  has three edges?

Comment: @RonnieBrown  Prof. Brown Thank you very  much for the information you provided. For the moment the book is not available to me. could you please more explain that why do you think this type of homology does not work?

Comment: @AliTaghavi Because you can stick two triangles ($\Delta^2$) together to create a quadrilateral. On the other hand, your disks are essentially two-sided "polygons", and sticking together two two-sided "polygons" gets you another two-sided "polygon". 3+3-2 (two triangles minus the two sides that cancel) = 4, but 2+2-2=2.

Comment: You can make any polygon out of triangles, but you can only make digons out of digons.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger  yes right. Now I see.

Comment: @Ali Taghavi The NAT book is available as a pdf from my web site www.groupoids.org.uk .    I see roughly how to prove with that background that such a theory could be set up and proved to work, as in my HHA paper, but I see difficulty doing this directly, at least I could not do it. The cubical theory is more expressive, though less "neat",  than the simplicial theory.  See also  arXiv:1610.07421 .